# Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, caracteres

Quais são as principais diferenças entre os "*encodings*" Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?

Todos eles são realmente *encodings* ou uns são apenas "sub-categorias" dos outros?

Não pretendo saber todos os detalhes de cada um, apenas uma breve de cada e, se possível, como se diferenciam entre si.

Comment: Eu iria traduzir [isso daqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/4843158), mas fiquei com preguiça de ver onde o Google "errou". Então deixo para outras respostas.

Comment: Logo que escrevi a pergunta eu procurei no SOzão (como de costume) e me deparei com essa. Se ninguém responder, eu mesmo traduzo. Acho interessante ter esse tipo de conteúdo aqui, por isso vou manter a pergunta num primeiro momento =D

Comment: Sua pergunta é excelente para ficar aqui. Só que depois que vejo as respostas do Jon Skeet eu fico com preguiça de responder algo parecido. kkkk

Comment: Eu te entendo, eu te entendo hahaha

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052

Comment: leia isso aqui - https://medium.com/@sestrem/o-m%C3%ADnimo-que-todo-desenvolvedor-deve-saber-sobre-unicode-e-character-sets-789a4229ecf5  é de 2003, do cirador do stackoverflow .

Comment: @jsbueno no meio desses 3 anos e pouco eu acabei lendo (e relendo) isto. Grato pela dica.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## ASCII

[American Standard Code for Information Interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Como o nome já diz é um padrão que atende bem os americanos. Ele vai do número 0 até 127, sendo que os 32 primeiros e o último são considerados de controle, os demais representam "caracteres imprimíveis", ou seja, reconhecidos por humanos. É bem universal. Pode ser representado com apenas 7 bits, ainda que normalmente se use um byte.

[image: Tabela ASCII]

Fica claro que não tem acentos, que os americanos não usam mesmo.

## ANSI

Não existe esta codificação.

O termo é American National Standards Institute, o equivalente à nossa [ABNT](http://www.abnt.org.br/).

Como ele estabeleceu algumas normas de uso de caracteres para atender demandas diversas, muitos *encodings* (na verdade páginas de códigos) acabam sendo chamados genericamente de ANSI, até para fazer um contraponto ao Unicode que é outra entidade com outro tipo de *encoding*. Normalmente essas páginas de códigos são consideradas extensões ao ASCII, mas nada impede que algum *encoding* específico não seja 100% compatível.

Novamente foi uma solução americana para lidar com caracteres internacionais já que o ASCII não atendia bem.

Dependendo do contexto, e até da época, quer dizer uma coisa diferente. Hoje o termo costuma ser usado para o [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) já que muito da documentação da Microsoft se refere ao seu *encoding* como ANSI. [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), também conhecido como Latin1, também é muito usado.

Todos *encodings* chamados de ANSI que conheço podem ser representados por 1 byte.

Então depende do que está falando.

## UTF

Sozinho não quer dizer muita coisa. É Unicode Transformation Format. Existem alguns *encodings* que usam esta sigla. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) e [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) são os *encodings* mais conhecidos.

Nos artigos da Wikipedia tem vários detalhes. Eles são bem complexos e quase ninguém sabe usar direito em toda sua plenitude, inclusive eu. A maioria das implementações estão erradas e/ou não atendem ao padrão, especialmente UTF-8.

O UTF-8 é compatível com o ASCII (ele aceita ASCII como caracteres válidos). Mas não com qualquer outro sistema de codificação de caracteres. É a codificação mais completa e mais complexa que existe. Alguns são apaixonados por ela (e este é o melhor termo que achei) e outros odeiam, ainda que reconheçam sua utilidade. É complexa para o humano (programador) entender e para o computador lidar.

O tamanho do UTF-8 e UTF-16 é variável, o primeiro de 1 à 4 bytes (dependendo da versão poderia ir até 6 bytes, mas na prática não acontece) e o segundo é 2 ou 4 bytes. O UTF-32 tem sempre 4 bytes.

Há uma [comparação entre eles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings). Não sei o quanto é preciso. Certamente não é completo.

## Unicode

É um padrão para representação de textos estabelecidos por um [consórcio](http://unicode.org/). Entre as normas estabelecidas por ele estão alguns *encodings*. Mas na verdade ele se refere a muito mais que isso. Originou do [Universal Coded Character Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) ou UCS que era bem mais simples e resolvia quase tudo o que precisava.

Um [artigo que todo mundo deveria ler](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), mesmo que não concorde com tudo o que tem lá.

Os conjuntos de caracteres suportados são separados em planos. Pode-se ter uma [visão geral sobre eles no artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)). Sendo o plano 0 ou BMP o mais usado, disparadamente.

Todos esses padrões são oficializados pela [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) que é a entidade internacional que regula normas técnicas.

Tem relação com UTF.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eita, ficou bem melhor :/ ... se eu soubesse que tu tava na área tinha esperado XD +1

Comment: É que eu fui fazendo de cabeça o que fui lembrando, depois sai corrento atrás de *links* e dar uma melhorada. Eu achei essa resposta no SO, achei mais ou menos, mas está certa, então tb ganhou +1 (meu último voto pra hoje)

Answer (score 14):

Conforme o [@randrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/4843158) linkou, fiz uma tradução rápida, removi algumas coisas sobre programação especifica e sobre coisas opinativas, também tentei não deixar ao pé da letra a tradução (meu inglês é +ou- vou revisar).

- "[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)" não é uma codificação especifica, ele se refere a qualquer codificação que usa a união de códigos para formar um caractere.
- [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16): São 2 bytes por "unidade de código".
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): Neste formato cada caractere varia entre 1 e 4 bytes. Sendo que valores ASCII usam 1 byte cada
- [UTF-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32): Este formato usa 4 bytes por "ponto de código" (provavelmente para formar um caractere).
- [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII): Usa um único byte para cada caractere, ele usa apenas 7bits para representar todos caracteres (O Unicode usa de 0-127), ele não inclui acentos e vários caracteres especiais.
- ANSI: Não há um padrão fixo para esta codificação, existem vários tipos na verdade. Um exemplo bem comum seria [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Outros tipo você pode encontrar informações em [unicode.org](http://unicode.org) e possivelmente este link pode lhe ser util [code charts](http://unicode.org/charts).

> ### Detalhe:
>
> 1 byte equivale a 8 bits