# O que aconteceu com o Unicode no Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou começando a usar o `Python3` aos poucos. Fui rodar um determinado código que eu costumava rodar com Python2.7 e obtive o seguinte erro:

> NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Sendo assim, entendo que `unicode` não exista em Python 3. O que devo utilizar no lugar dele?

Comment: Pode postar qual trecho de código, especificamente? Em tempo, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Não precisa de código. Qualquer chamava de `unicode(minha_string)` gera o erro descrito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877309/221800) do [Martjin Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) o tipo [Unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101) foi renomeado para `str`, que é mais intuitivo, e o antigo `str` foi renomeado para `bytes`. Ele coloca um código para lidar quando não se sabe qual é a codificação:

```
if isinstance(unicode_or_str, str):
    text = unicode_or_str
    decoded = False
else:
    text = unicode_or_str.decode(encoding)
    decoded = True
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/UnicodeType.py).

Answer (score 1):

Essa mudança na verdade é a principal mudança do Python 2 para o Python 3 - e 
basicamente por conta dela que optaram pela transição com quebra de compatibilidade. Todo o texto em Python3 agora é "texto", não tem um mapeamento 1:1 automático para valores em bytes. Na prática a classe `str` passa a se comportar exatamente como a classe "unicode" se comportava em Python 2.

A partir da versão 3.3 do Python, para facilitar a escrita de programas que pudessem funcionar simultâneamente em Python 2 e Python3, o prefixo `u` para strings foi re-introduzido. Em Python 2, esse prefixo implicava que a string era "unicode", não "str". Em Python 3, ele não faz absolutamente nada - a string continua sendo "unicode". Ex.: `u"maçã"` , `b"nao pode ter acentos"`

Em contrapartida, o prefixo `b` que não fazia nada em Python2, indica que se está escrevendo um objeto do tipo `bytes` em Python 3. Esse, por outro lado, embora possa ser usado em APIs que esperam realmente valores em bytes (com texto já codificado segundo alguma convenção para os acentos, os chamados "encodings" (ex. : latin1, utf-8, cp-852)). Mas sobretudo, em Python 3 se você tentar recuperar um único elemento de um objeto "str/bytes" no Python 2, o resultado é um objeto "str/bytes" de comprimento 1. Em Python 3, você recebe um número entre 0 e 255 - como acontece com as strings de ponteiro de char em C:

Python 2:

```py
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = b"apple"
>>> a[0]
'a'
>>> b = "maçã"
>>> len(b)
6
>>> b = u"maçã"
>>> len(b)
4
```

Python 3.8.0+ (heads/3.8:d04661f, Oct 24 2019, 09:19:45) 
Python 3:

```py
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = b"apple"
>>> a[0]
97
>>> b = "maçã"
>>> len(b)
4
>>> b = u"maçã"
>>> len(b)
4
>>> b[3]
'ã'
```

Para quem ainda não está familiarizado com "unicode" e "texto como bytes", sugiro a leitura de um artigo escrito em 2003 pelo Joel (o fundador do stackoverflow):https://www.scribd.com/document/3181016/Programacao-Joel-on-Unicode