# Qual a diferença entre char, nchar, varchar e nvarchar?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, string, tipagem, codificação-de-caracteres

- Qual a diferença entre usar os tipos de dados `varchar` e `nvarchar`?
- `nvarchar` existe em todo banco de dados SQL?
- Existe alguma diferença significante de performance entre ambos?
- Existe um critério para utilizá-los?

E vi que também existe o mesmo com `char` e `nchar`. O mesmo se aplica a eles?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tem a ver com a codificação de caracteres. O `NVARCHAR` é um tipo *multibyte* para armazenar textos [Unicode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101).

Até onde eu sei só existe no SQL Server, ele não faz parte do padrão. A pergunta tem a *tag* de MySQL, mas ele não aceita esse tipo.

Há diferença intrínseca de performance já que a codificação usada pelo `NVARCHAR` tem várias desvantagens.

Eu adoto `VARCHAR` até que precise do `NVARCHAR`. Na maioria dos meus problemas eles são suficientes. O uso de Latin1 me serve muito bem e ganho espaço e performance. Há quem adote `NVARCHAR` por padrão, ou "por via das dúvidas", não gosto desse tipo de atitude.

O mesmo se aplica ao tipo de caracteres, a diferença é que nesses terão tamanho de caracteres fixos, enquanto que os outros são os tipos com tamanhos variáveis. Não confundir com o tamanho em bytes que no `NCHAR` pode variar.

O `NVARCHAR` pode ter uma quantidade de bytes diferentes da quantidade de caracteres, e depende da codificação e *collate*  usadas, pode ser o dobro do tamanho, pode depender do conteúdo, a variação depende da codificação. Em `VARCHAR` a quantidade bytes é o mesmo da quantidade de caracteres, mais o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) de controle (atualmente 24 bytes), claro. Por isso pode armazenar menos caracteres.

- [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sugiro que essa resposta seja atualizada e/ou corrigida. A resposta em inglês (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) a essa mesma pergunta trouxe outros pontos importantes que precisam ser levados em consideração, independentemente de ser MySQL ou SQL Server: 1) Os sistemas operacionais hoje já trabalham com Unicode, então, se uso varchar, tenho um overhead para "converter" para unicode tanto ao ler quanto ao salvar; 2) Espaço em disco é menos custoso do que problemas de codepage/caracteres; 3) etc (veja a resposta, é bem interessante).

Comment: Não vi nada de errado ou desatualizado nesta resposta por isso não sei o que eu poderia mudar. Algumas dessas proposições são só opiniões, por isso fico com a minhas, mas respeitos as diferentes, e resposta apontada no SOen é simplista e equivocada, apesar de todos os votos, e principalmente não considera o meu contexto que pra mim é mais importante. Para outros contextos as pessoas devam analisar o que melhor se encaixa para ela, usar uma solução padrão para todo mundo é um erro.

Answer (score 14):

O datatype varchar considera caracteres não-UNICODE, o nvarchar, ao contrário, trabalha com caracteres UNICODE.

O que você tem que levar em consideração é a quantidade armazenada por cada tipo de dado.

O VARCHAR irá armazenar a quantidade informada, acrescida de 2bytes. Por exemplo, um campo VARCHAR(10) irá armazenar, no máximo, 10bytes + 2bytes. Estes dois bytes a mais são justamente por conta de ser um tipo de dado de tamanho variável.

Já o NVARCHAR irá ocupar o dobro do espaço mais os 2bytes de controle. Então, no mesmo exemplo, um campo NVARCHAR(10) irá ocupar 20bytes + 2bytes.

Isso fará muita diferença para o seu armazenamento e deve ser levado em consideração.

[Fonte](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/a7a526b9-8ef9-465f-8a9b-c88a37f0e983/varchar-ou-nvarchar?forum=admingeralpt)

---

A grosso modo, no mundo CHAR e VARCHAR, cada carácter ocupa 1 byte. Um byte é um conjunto de 8bits e considerando todas as posições desses bits (ligado e desligado) podemos ter 256 combinações (2^8). Isso quer dizer que um byte é capaz de representar 256 combinações diferentes. Para o alfabeto americano isso é mais que suficiente, para o alfabeto latino isso também é mais que suficiente.

O problema começa quando consideramos alfabetos árabes, asiáticos, gregos, etc. Nesse caso, se formos considerar todas as letras e caracteres possíveis iremos extrapolar todas as 256 combinações que 1 byte pode representar. Para essa situações surgiu o NVARCHAR e o NCHAR. Para esses tipos de dados cada caractér ocupa 2bytes. Se um byte pode expressar 256 combinações (2^8), dois bytes podem armazenar 65536 combinações (2^16). Com essa quantidade de combinações, é possível representar qualquer caractér existente só que o custo de armazenamento fica maior.

Se você utilizar os tipos CHAR e VARCHAR e tentar armazenar determinados caracteres, o universo de caracteres disponíveis ficará restrito a collation que você escolheu. Se você tentar armazenar outro carácter que não esteja contemplado por essa collation, esse carácter será convertido para algum aproximado. Se você escolher NCHAR e NVARCHAR, então essa limitação não ocorre.

[Fonte](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/df40877c-a250-468e-b425-a6c46245f1e2/nvarchar-x-varchar?forum=transactsqlpt)