# Converter códigos utf-8 para unicode

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, unicode, replace

Pois bem, tenho um arquivo *JSON* onde todos os símbolos *unicode* como esse  "★" estão nesse formato: "\u2605" tem alguma forma de converter esses códigos para os símbolos quando meu programa *NodeJS* ler o *JSON*?

Exemplo de como é: `{"name":"\u2605 Bayonet","price":15713,"have":6,"max":6}`

Exemplo de como quero que fique: `{"name":"★ Bayonet","price":15713,"have":6,"max":6}`

Até fiz manualmente um *replace* para esses códigos, porém quando executo ele repete duas vezes o *JSON* dando *replace* apenas na primeira vez e não armazena na variável o *JSON* alterado.

Meu código:

```
Trade.prototype.getSteamapis = function getSteamapis(callback) {
  fs.readFile(`./prices/730.json`,'utf8',function (err,body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    body.replace("/\u2605/g","★")
    body.replace("/\u2605 /g","★")
    body.replace("/\u9f8d/g","龍")
    body.replace("/\u58f1/g","壱")
    body.replace("/\u2122/g","™")
    body.replace("/\u5f10/g","弐")
    body.replace("/\u738b/g","王")
    console.log(body)
    return body
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Não que vá resolver para o seu caso, mas quando você faz o `replace` tem que atribuir à variável: `body = body.replace("/\u2605/g","★");`. E mais uma coisa: Tem certeza que os arquivos já não estão sendo salvos com o código e o `Node.js` está lendo corretamente?

Comment: pois bem sim achei um erro na hora da leitura, porem ele só me mostrou que o raplace nao está funcionando :[

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, esses caracteres `\uXXXXX` não são UTF-8, são caracteres "escapados" (na verdade qualquer caractere pode ser escapado assim).

Segundo, isto o que você quer não é converter UTF-8 para Unicode, é apenas fazer o inverso de "escape", seria um "unescape".

Para entender as "supostas diferenças" diferenças entre UTF-8 e Unicode recomendo que leia isto:

- [Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/3635)

Então **não é necessário** converter nada, isso é um tipo de "escape" para evitar "truncar os dados", basta fazer o teste, no momento que popular o JSON em um elemento HTML ele irá ser reproduzido como deve, desde que sua página use o `charset=UTF-8`.

Então supondo que tua página tenha o header na resposta do servidor:

```
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

E/Ou a tag (se for um navegador com suporte para HTML5):

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Navegadores um pouco mais antigos:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Basta popular o Json (supondo que a resposta tenha vindo de qualquer lugar, por exemplo via Ajax ou já estivesse dentro da tag `<script>`):

```js
var meujson = {"name":"\u2605 Bayonet","price":15713,"have":6,"max":6};

document.getElementById("foo-name").textContent = meujson.name;
```

```html
<div id="foo-name"></div>
```

Esses escapes são necessários, como eu disse anteriormente, para evitar perdas de caracteres em diferentes codificações.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = "{\"name\":\"\\u2605 Bayonet\",\"price\":15713,\"have\":6,\"max\":6}";
var s2 = JSON.parse('"' + s.replace(/\"/g, '\\"') + '"');
document.write(s2);
```

Me baseei [nesta resposta aqui no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40410744/540552) e também [nesta daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12869914/540552).

A ideia é que o `JSON.parse` é capaz de fazer as conversões necessárias. Mas como você quer converter uma string (independente do fato de coincidentemente ela ser um JSON) e ter como saída uma string, o `'"' + s.replace(/\"/g, '\\"') + '"'` acrescenta as aspas duplas no começo e faz o escaping das aspas duplas que ocorrerem no texto, garantindo que o resultado será um string.