# O que são as indicações colocadas antes de strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Em python, observei que essas "indicações" foram colocadas em dois casos, primeiro, em strings antes de passarem por um algoritmo de hash, ex:

> import hashlib
>
> m = hashlib.sha256()
>
> m.update(b"Nobody inspects")

Obs: A indicação a que me refiro, é o 'b' antes de "Nobody inspects"

E segundo antes de as strings passarem pelo 'encode' :

> plaintext = u'algor\u00edtimo'
>
> encodedtext = plaintext.encode('utf-8')

Obs: A indicação dessa vez é o 'u' antes de 'algor\u00edtimo'

Gostaria de saber o que significam, pois em python para se usar um print ou algo parecido não é necessário (pelo menos até onde sei) usar essas "indicações", exceto em casos no qual vai se usar a biblioteca hashlib por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre em um terminal python 2.7 e faça:

```
str1 = 'teste'
str2 = 'teste'
```

Agora veja o tipo das duas:

```
type(str1)
str

type(str2)
unicode
```

Python 2 precisa do `u'` para indicar que a string é unicode (para trabalhar com a nossa acentuação, por exemplo), se vc fizer o mesmo teste no python 3, vai perceber que ess `u'` se tornou desnecessário.

Agora volte no terminal (pode ser python 2 ou 3) faça:

```
str1 = 'string1'
str2 = b'string1'
```

Agora vejamos os tipos dessas strings:

```
print (type(str1))
<class 'str'>

print (type(str2))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Veja essa observação da documentção:

> Atenção: Enquanto string são sequencias de caracteres (representados por strings de tamanho 1), os objetos bytes e bytearray são sequencias de inteiros (de 0 a 255), representando os valores ASCII de cada byte. Isto significa que para um objeto byte ou bytearray, b[0] retornara um inteiro. [Veja o texto completo aqui.](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

O `b` é para indicar que o objeto é do tipo bytes.

Agora retorne ao terminal e faça:

```
str1 = 'Linha 1\nLinha 2'
str2 = r'Linha 1\nLinha 2'
```

Veja agora, a diferença das duas ao executar um `print` nas mesmas:

```
print (str1)
Linha 1
Linha 2

print (str2)
Linha 1\nLinha 2
```

O `r` (de raw) indica que é uma string "crua", qualquer caracter de escape será deseconsiderado.

Answer (score 2):

São indicativos de qual literal de *string* será colocado ali, cada um tem uma característica diferente em que o compilador/interpretador entende de forma diferente e decide o que fazer. Tem [documentação de toda análise léxica](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) que é feita no código.

No caso o `u` indica que a *string* está codificada como [UTF-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101) e o `b` como bytes sem codificação específica (usa ASCII), neste caso não será tratado como um tipo `str`. Ainda pode usar `r` em conjunto para indicar que é um texto bruto e caracteres especiais não são tratados de forma especial.