# Qual encoding usar quando se trata de acento?

Tags: java

Existem tanto encoding... Já procurei bastante no Google e não conseguir diferenciar quando usar cada um desses aqui

```
ISO-8859-1
UTF-8
LATIN1
cp...
```

Veja, eu estava com problema com relação aos nossos acentos, tentei de cara o UTF-8 pois sempre achei que se tratando de acentos seria o UTF-8, porém, não funcionou... Depois de muito pesquisar tentei o ISO-8859-1 e adivinha funcionou... Por quê?

Comment: A ISO-8859-1 é uma codificação de alfabeto latino, mas ao que eu sei a ISO descontinuou ele, mas se funciona pra você continue usando. talvez tenha haver com sua ide difícil saber com poucas informações

Answer (score 2):

Em geral o mais utilizado seria o **UTF-8**, visto que suporta todo o alfabeto e acentos além de uma gama gigantesca de caracteres especiais,quanto ao seu problema com a acentuação existem diversas causas para o problema, pode variar de falta de configuração em alguma parte do código ou configuração errada no editor de texto/IDE(causa mais comum).

Pelo oque eu conheço sobre o assunto o UTF-8 geralmente é utilizado para internacionalização de um texto(embora comumente utilizado nacionalmente também) enquanto o ISO-8859-1 geralmente é utilizado para encoding de textos nacionais.

A razão da diferença está na forma como o texto é codificado a ISO-8859-1 codifica o texto que é diferente da UTF-8, enquanto a UTF-8 suporta todos os caracteres unicode enquanto a ISO-8859-1 só suporta os primeiros 256(se eu não me engano).

Esta resposta no Stack consegue explicar melhor do que eu:
[Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156951/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-unicode-utf-ascii-ansi)

Answer (score 0):

> A ISO-8859-1 é uma codificação de alfabeto latino, mas ao que eu sei a ISO descontinuou ele, mas se funciona pra você continue usando. talvez tenha haver com sua ide difícil saber com poucas informações

Antes de começar, que apenas explicar uma coisa sobre o comentário do Rodrigo, muita gente pensa isso também, não é que ISO-8859-1 tenha sido "descontinuado", simplesmente ele não tem muito mais o que evoluir, o UTF-8 já supri e procuraram focar no UTF-8 as evoluções necessárias, o ISO-8859-1 só não vai mais evoluir, não quer dizer que ele não seja usável, dizer que é descontinuado soa como algo sendo "não recomendado" ou vai parar de "funcionar", o que pode levar a falsas interpretações.

O ISO-8859-1 pode ser usado tranquilamente se o seu App vai ser em português e se não necessitar de emojis ou multi-idiomas.

---

### ISO-8859-1 vs UTF-8

O ISO-8859-1 é um Conjuntos de caracteres gráficos codificados de byte único (8-bit) e consiste em of [191 caracteres](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm)

O UTF-8 é uma codificação que entre 1 e 4 bytes para cada caractere, e atualmente suporta muitos caracteres e é um dos mais usados em websites

Ou seja são duas codificações diferentes, por exemplo a letra acentuada `à` (a com crase) tem códigos diferentes em ambas codificações:

- UTF-8 o `à` tem o seguinte código: `c3 a0`
- iso-8859-1 o `à` tem o seguinte código: `E0`

> (se as tabelas que pesquisei estiverem corretas)

Então note que em utf-8 foi `c3 a0` e no iso: `E0`, ou seja mesmo que para nós humanos pareça a mesma coisa, não é, no UTF-8 foi usado 2 bytes diferentes, o que fez o "uni-code"

Resumindo ambas suportam acentos, a questão é que o dependendo da aplicação, framework ou afins, o projeto poderá ser padrão UTF-8 ou usar windows-1252 ("compativel" com iso-8859-1), se você estiver lendo um arquivo de texto e tentando exibir e na sua aplicação é porque o conteúdo do arquivo de texto esta em um formato compatível ao ISO-8859-1 e por isso definir no projeto UTF-8 não vai funcionar.

O mesmo vale para um banco de dados, se o charset definido na tabela do banco for latin1 (compatível com o ISO-8859-1) então não tem como usar utf-8 no projeto (se bem que dependendo do banco é possível ajustar e até conseguir algum resultado), então respondendo ao título da pergunta:

> Qual codificação usar quando se trata de acento?

O ISO-8859-1 tanto quanto o UTF-8 suportam acentos, vai depender de onde esta pegando os dados, como um banco de dados ou um arquivo de texto, se todos arquivos ou tabelas do banco usarem UTF-8 então o projeto terá que estar em UTF-8, se estiverem em ISO-8859-1 (banco ou arquivos de texto) terá que usar ISO-8859-1 em seu projeto

---

### Salvando um arquivo

Supondo que esteja usando o um editor de textos como notepad++ (que é melhor que o nativo do windows para isto) antes de salvar você pode converter o seu documento de texto (se for o seu caso) para ANSI (que será compatível com o iso-8859-1) ou para UTF-8:

[image: notepad++]

Se salvar como UTF-8 o documento de texto e no seu projeto Java tentar usar iso-8859-1 eles **vão conflitar** e caracteres vão se perder no momento de exibir, o mesmo vale ao contrário, se salvar o documento como ANSI e definir o projeto como UTF-8 vai falhar, ou seja use em tudo sempre a mesma codificação se possível, pois senão terá que ficar usando codificadores e decodificadores dentro da aplicação.