# Quando escolher entre utilizar uma string wide ou não?

Tags: c++, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Quando utilizar uma *string wide* (`std::wstring`) ou uma *string* normal (`std::string`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pergunta difícil de responder.

Há uma tendência de usar [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) no Linux e outras plataformas que usam codificações que tem garantidamente 1 byte por caractere ou que os caracteres sejam construídos por um conjunto de bytes com quantidade definida pelo próprio conjunto onde o exemplo mais usado é o UTF-8.

No Windows costuma-se usar `wstring` que usam caracteres garantidamente de mais de 1 byte. Ele é largo. O UTF-16 ou UTF-32 são os mais usados.

Mesmo nestas plataformas muitas vezes é melhor usar `string`. Se a interação direta com o sistema operacional for pequena pode compensar, mesmo que eventualmente precise de uma conversão o ganho no geral por ser maior. Mas é bem difícil acertar o ponto.

Muitas vezes usamos alguma biblioteca que abstrai isso. Nem sempre é o ideal.

Aqui vai uma polêmica não tão relacionada ao C++. Eu tento usar, sempre que possível codificações, com tamanho garantido, prioritariamente [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)/[Latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ou algo parecido (quase sempre consigo), se não der vou de [UCS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (é quase o UTF-16) e finalmente o [UCS-4/UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) (nunca usei, mas hoje tem aplicação que pode ser necessário por mais um erro que a entidade que define esses padrões cometeu). Só uso [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) e UTF-16 quando preciso "conversar" com recursos externos a aplicação e que não tenho controle sobre o seu uso.

Veja [Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101).

Comment: Vale ressaltar que, infelizmente, `std::basic_string` (as strings de C++) não conhecem Unicode, pois elas tratam os dados como apenas bytes (pode ser pensado como _code units_) e não como caracteres. Por isso é necessário usar bibliotecas que reconhecem tais codificações (como a [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)).