# Validação do tamanho de strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Estava criando uma função para validar campos de texto grandes (descrição, observação, ...), que, no SQL, serão salvos como `TEXT`, então basicamente fiz isso:

```
function($valor, $min = 0, $max = 65000) {
    if (strlen($valor) >= $min || strlen($valor) <= $max) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Quando fui procurar o tamanho máximo dos campos do tipo `TEXT` do achei [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932750) do SOen que responde a isso, e nela mostra que o tamanho do texto depende dos caracteres da string. Na verdade os tipos de textos não tem um limite de caracteres mas sim um limite de bytes, então duas perguntas:

- Como validar uma entrada de texto de acordo com o tamanho máximo de bytes que aquela string deve conter?
- Essa validação é necessária apenas em campos `TINYTEXT`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, e `LONGTEXT`?

Comment: Não adicionei a tag `mysql` porque acredito que a pergunta seja relevante para mais de um banco de dados

Comment: Não entendi essa lógica, se `$valor` for 0 (zero)  deve retornar `true`?

Comment: Se o tamanho do valor for maior que o mínimo e menor que o máximo @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: https://ideone.com/YOph1P

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo `$valor` é o texto

Comment: na verdade queria dizer $valor="";

Comment: A tag é fundamental, pq os DBs lidam de maneira diferente com isso. MySQL, por exemplo, não mede CHAR e VARCHAR em bytes, e sim e caracteres e isso pode influir em detalhes das respostas. O encoding também é fundamental, pois essa preocupação sua só faz diferença em encodings multibyte (que infelizmente são usados à toa pela maior parte dos desenvolvedores - programador que sabe o que tá fazendo é uma minoria, o resto é só seguidor de moda).

Comment: Por exemplo, se não precisar de suporte a emoticons (que costumam ser bobeira em boa parte das aplicações) e não for usar línguas orientais, o Latin 1 só tem vantagens. Mais veloz, menos espaço, todos os caracteres das linguas latinas, etc.

Comment: @Bacco no caso uso UTF-8

Comment: E precisa? Outra coisa. Pra que text se seu limite é 65000 bytes? E se precisa mais, use um LONGTEXT então. Todos esses formatos variáveis, por mais que você abuse deles, vão gastar no máximo 4 bytes a mais. 65000 bytes cabe em Varchar, que dá pra mais de 15000 caracteres UTF8 dos mais complexos

Comment: Em outras palavras: se usar Latin 1 (pode ser só naquele campo, o MySQL permite) ganha 4x o limite de espaço, ou se usar UTF-8 com limite 15000 cabe no varchar, ou se usar LONGTEXT pode limitar a 1/4 do valor máximo sem medo. E sem IFs à toa.

Comment: @Bacco valeu pela explicação, no final usarei o `VARCHAR`, vou estudar um pouco mais os encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

Mas não é tão simples. Isso pode ser um problema para a usabilidade do usuário. Não deve importuná-lo com detalhes de implementação. Como vai informá-lo do que fazer em algo que ele não enxerga? Ou terá que fazer um algoritmo extremamente complexo ou importunará com tentativas e erros. Esse é só um dos motivos que eu considero o uso de *encodings multi byte* um erro.

A nossa indústria meio que definiu que iria usar UTF-8 por padrão, eu prefiro Latin-1 ou algo parecido. [Qualquer *encoding single byte* funciona melhor em ocupação de espaço e processamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30220/101).

Este é um dos motivos para preferir o `VARCHAR` que não tem esse problema. Se achar que não pode usar, prefira um `LONGTEXT` de tamanho aberto e seja feliz. Mas quase sempre o `TEXT` é um erro.

Uma solução é colocar um espaço maior. Em geral, em UTF-8, se colocar o dobro de caracteres já está bem protegido, a não ser que espera nomes em chinês, klingon ou coisa do tipo. Aí não importa os bytes. Eu iria por esse caminho.

Veja mais em:

- [Quais os tipos de dados existentes no MySQL para textos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78812/101)
- [Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101)
- [Por que ainda se usam outras codificações além do UTF-8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30587/101)
- [Quando escolher entre utilizar uma string wide ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266152/101)

Comment: Acredito que um simples "Tamanho máximo excedido" seja o suficiente

Comment: Qual seria o `encoding` que devo passar?

Comment: Então, o que eu falei, deixa ele adivinhar qual é o máximo que ele pode usar, não dá nenhuma indicação do que está errado de fato, só algo por cima. Por isso a maioria dos softwares são ruins de usar hoje em dia.

Comment: O software no caso é para um sistema interno, se alguém tiver uma dúvida pode perguntar pro suporte, além disso o tamanho máximo que o sistema irá receber muito dificilmente irá chegar a mais de 500 caracteres. É apenas para ter certeza que não irá tentar passar algo que não devia para o banco

Comment: Então tá ok, o suporte é feito pra isso mesmo.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, olhando o 1° link da lista vou ficar com `VARCHAR` mesmo. Vou deixar a pergunta aberta ainda para caso alguma pessoa responda a segunda pergunta

Comment: Já li os links que passou e, com algumas outras coisas que já havia lido, acho que entendi mais ou menos como funcionam e a diferença entre alguns, você teria alguma fonte confiável mais completa? (com mais opções além das já mencionadas nos links, diferenças de tamanho, performance, compatibilidade, flexibilidade, etc). Outra pergunta, a diferença de performance e armazenamento entre algo mais complexo como UTF-8 e algo mais simples como ANSI só vai ser perceptível manipulando arquivos grandes, correto? Ou a diferença é considerável mesmo em campos simples (nome, endereço, descrição, etc)?

Comment: Não, não e depende.

Comment: Valeu a pena abrir uma pergunta sobre a segunda parte? (diferença de armazenamento e performance)

Comment: Não sei, precisa ver se já não foi tudo respondido em outras perguntas.