# Para que serve o "L" antes de uma string em C++?

Tags: c++, string

Notei que alguns frameworks e engines obrigam que a string seja passada com **`L`** antes do texto. A [Irrlicht Engine](https://irrlicht.sourceforge.io) é um exemplo.

```
myObject->setLabel(L"my string");
```

Qual a finalidade desse **`L`** na string?

Comment: ele cria uma string do tipo `wchar_t` no lugar uma string normal (com tipo `char`), pode ler mais a respeito desse tipo aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=msvc-160

Comment: Isso é uma string wide (cada caractere será armazenado em multibyte) - não confunda com utf 8 ou 16, é tamanho fixo por caractere. Enquanto não tem resposta formal, pode dar uma lidinha em [Quando escolher entre utilizar uma string wide ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266152/70) para uma referência.

Answer (score 0):

'L' representa um wchar_t. É um prefixo para literais de caracteres largos (wide characters).
É um built in type que pode representar valores distintos. Pode ter 2 bytes ou 4 bytes de memória e contém caracteres UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

O caractere **L** antes de um *string literal* (como `"Hello"` ou `"World"`, por exemplo), serve para indicar que o *string literal* em questão utiliza *wide characters* (nos quais cada caractere pode utilizar mais de um byte de memória para ser armazenado). Assim sendo, cadeias de caracteres como `L"Hello world!"` ou `L"Foo bar"` são chamadas de ***wide string literals***.

#### Um pouco mais sobre os *wide string literals*.

Segundo o [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), o tipo de um *wide string literal* é ***const wchar_t[N]***, em que N é o tamanho em unidades de código da codificação "larga" (*wide*) usada no sistema em questão, incluindo o caractere nulo de terminacão `\0`.

> The type of a L"..." string literal is const wchar_t[N], where N is the size of the string in code units of the execution wide encoding (until C++23)wide literal encoding (since C++23), including the null terminator.

Logo, no seu exemplo, `L"my string"` é um desses ***wide string literals***, e seu tamanho é de 10 dessas unidades de código com "codificação larga" (incluindo o caractere `'\0'`), que podem ter 16 bits, 32 bits etc, a depender do conjunto básico de caracteres usado pelo sistema. Por exemplo, se na sua máquina forem usados *code units* de 8 bits (ou seja, um *char* básico tem 8 bits), talvez o tamanho dos *code units* usados para cada um dos chars em um *wide string literal* seja 16 bits.