# Problema com Encoding Perdendo Acentuação

Tags: c#, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Recebo um arquivo (*.txt) que vem como encode padrão o ANSI.

Porém sempre que leio o arquivo ele me retorna "?" em todos caracteres que possuem algum tipo de acento ou até mesmo o próprio "ç".

Formas que eu tentei:

```
File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF8")
```

Mas sempre quando "printo" a String no console, ou escrevo em um arquivo ele sempre retorna os acentuações como "?".

Comment: ANSI não é uma codificação é como se fosse um "conjunto" delas (como Unicode). Para você ler um arquivo, vai precisar saber a codificação específico dele. Não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as principais diferenças entre Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156951)

Comment: Use o Default, quando utilizo o UTF8  não funciona